# Pass array parameter to XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, xmlhttprequest

How can i pass an array object to my url parameters on XMLHttpRequest?
I have tried to pass my_array but the object is undefined. But if i put a console.log of my_array on anonymous function the object is filled correctly

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "exampleUrl="+my_array+"&api_key="+api+"&format=json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        my_array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //console.log(my_array);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), but you should take care of things like `null`, `undefined`, functions, objects, native types like a date, etc. Since you want to use JSON.parse on the other end, you should use JSON.stringify when sending the data.

Basically `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))`. Example: `[1,'string',null,12.34]` gets to be "%5B1%2C%22string%22%2Cnull%2C12.34%5D"

There are other things to think about, for example the URL of a GET request has some length limitations. Why not use jQuery, in which case you send everything you want in a data object and it takes care of it for you?

Your code, also, is wrong, unless the content of the `exampleUrl` parameter query parameter is returned by the server as the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with JSON.stringify i got a strange object output structure with backlash. Something like this: "{\"friends\":{\"user\":[{\"name\":\"listherine20\",\"image\":[...... how can i access to object value with this sintax with backlash?

Comment: JSON.stringify turns a Javascript object to JSON notation (a string). JSON.parse turns the string into an object again.

Answer (score 0):

You may use, **JSON.stringify()** method when creating the url.

```
var url = "exampleUrl?"+JSON.stringify(my_array)+"&api_key="+api+"&format=json";
```